# About the Town Pets

Tags: terraria

A while ago the Terraria 1.4 update came by. And very soon i documented myself about everything new. Except a few things i still don't understand. About town Pets, that is.

The Zoologist is a new NPC that will sell Licenses for having pets in your world. And upon using one, a random breed of that animal will appear the next morning. I know you can't select the breed or name of the pet, nor re-using a License to call a replacement. But if your pet somehow *dies*, does that make it reset it's breed/name or it remains like the one you got forever?

And another thing. Can you make them have a specific home instead of the one selected randomly? I know you can do that with NPC's once, but i don't know about pets.

I want to take a Pet Bunny soon, so this information is pretty important to me. Does anyone know the answer to any of these 2 questions?

Answer (score 1):

Pets function just like town NPCs, including counting towards the limit needed for a pylon to function. If they die, a random pet of the same type will show up, and they can be assigned to specific homes in the same manner as an NPC (although of course they can share a home with an NPC).

Comment: So... does that mean that if i get a Angora breed Bunny it's always going to be like that? or is it going to be a different breed when it dies?